# I make correction, i want to know the sum of this series 1*2+2*3+3*4...........+99*100

Tags: summation

I want to know the sum of this series 1*2+2*3+3*4...........+99*100
sorry, in previous question, I have mistakenly mentioned the wrong series.
thank & sorry for inconvenience

Comment: $1.2$ means $1\cdot 2$ or $\frac{12}{10}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{990} (1+\frac{n}{10})$? Or maybe $\sum_{n=1}^{981} (1+\frac{n}{10})$ with the last term equal to $99.1=991/10$.

Comment: @emiliocba I suspect $1.2$ actually means $1\cdot 2$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Something is wrong, looking at the first few terms..it appears it is going from $1\cdot2+1\cdot3....1\cdot100+2\cdot2+2\cdot3...2\cdot100....99\cdot100$ giving us $100*99$ terms?

Comment: You need to clarify your question if you want any kind of answer to it. Please edit your question to address the concerns raised in the comments.

Comment: "General formula of mentioned series is $j(j+1)$": no, this isn't the general formula.

Comment: So, you are looking for $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 100} ij?$$

Comment: In particular, you should tell us what $j(j+1)$ has to do with your sum, which has terms $1\cdot 3$ and $1\cdot 4$, which are not of this form.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$(1+2+3+\dots+n)^2 = \left(1^2+2^2+\dots +n^2\right) + 2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}ij$$

Comment: quite a big hint...............+1